# Get the App Namespace in Laravel 5

Tags: namespaces, laravel-5

I am developing a package for Laravel 5, but if a user change the default namespace of the application the package by command `php artisan app:name Test` won't work properly. the package needs to know the App's namespace to work properly.

Based on my understanding the Laravel 5 doesn't provide the namespace of the app in any of its core classes

So I decided either to get this namespace from the `composer.json` file

```
   "psr-4": {
        "AppNamespace\\": "app/"
    }
```

or ask the user to provide the namespace of the application in a kind of config file.

Question:
please let me know if my presumption about Laravel doesn't provide this is correct and if it is correct please let me know which way is the best way to get this `namespace` or if you have any better suggestion?

Comment: Your package shouldn't depend on the namespace of an application. For what exactly do you need to know it?

Comment: @lukasgeiter it creates some classes in the main the application for example a controller, in order to reference that controller later on we need to have the namespace of the app for example : `App\Http\Controllers\PackageController` you have any better suggestion?

Comment: In my case the package wants to interact with the existing user model, this does require the app namespace, answer below (trait) very helpful :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the app's namespace by using the below trait that is included to the core of Laravel:

```
Illuminate\Console\AppNamespaceDetectorTrait
```

Laravel uses this trait in the `AppNameCommand` to get the current namespace before it updated.

An example:

```
class MyClass {

    use \Illuminate\Console\AppNamespaceDetectorTrait;

    public function getNamespace()
    {
        return $this->getAppNamespace();
    }

}
```

You can read more about the traits [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php).

Comment: could you provide an example please

Comment: `MyClass` doesn't have to extend form any Class?

Comment: The above is just a simple example. You should import the trait to the class that you would like to get the namespace.

Comment: I see that this is an example, what I mean is this any class just can call  function `getAppNamespace()` ? or `MyClass` has to extend from a specific class

Comment: It doesn't need to extend the class. When you import a trait, you can call any method inside the trait.

Comment: if i have multiple traits and extended class your $this->getAppNamespace(); wouldnt work

Answer (score 0):

Check this one , it might be helpful for you   https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.nsconstants.php
You can use Magic Keyword _**_NAMESPACE__** to the namespace of any class from its methods.

Comment: Link is fine but expires over time so please add context here how to use it in relation to OP of question. (From Review).